# /auth/failure?message=service_unavailable&strategy=linkedin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api, omniauth

Linkedin authentication was working fine from more than a year, and suddenly from yesterday it is giving failure while signup with linkedin.

I'm not sure what had happen.

Following is the failure callback url while signup

```
/auth/failure?message=service_unavailable&strategy=linkedin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a Linkedin issue.

https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/service-temporarily-unavailable

Comment: Thanks for that link.They are not responding after posting issue yesterday.